# Disabling "Open" in elFinder

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, elfinder

Does anybody know a way to disable or in some way modify the "open" functionality in elFinder?

I'm using this in an ASP.NET MVC site and have added additional server-side filtering for file permissions and whatnot.  So users don't have direct access to files, everything has to go through the server-side component that feeds elFinder.  Thus, whenever someone tries to directly open a file, they get a 404 response.

There are a couple of UX pieces affected by this:

- Double-clicking a file - I am able to override the `dblclick` elFilder event and simply `return false`.  However, this carries the undesirable effect that one can't double-click folders to open them.
- Clicking the "open" menu item - I tried removing the `'open'` option from the `commands` configuration, but the option was still there.  A lot of other items were removable (renaming, uploading, anything other than read-only access which I'm denying users in this case), but this one isn't for some reason.
- Clicking the link in the "info" pop-up.  Not sure how to address this one.  Maybe customize the "info" pop-up with some template?

Has anybody run into this before and come up with any novel solutions?  I'm not against modifying the actual JavaScript for elFinder as a last resort (that would make it operationally more of a pain if I ever want to upgrade elFinder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to add **getfilecallback** as follow:

**$('#finder').elfinder({**

```
    url : 'php/connector.php',
    getFileCallback : function(files, fm) {
            return false;
    }
```

**});**

Comment: I _really_ like this option.  It doesn't require modifying the tool, so upgrades will be seamless.  It's a supported option (one that I just missed, apparently).  And best of all, `files` and `fm` give me all the information I need to meaningfully respond in an entirely different way, which was my next goal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Copy** the **open.js** file from **js/commands** sub-directory and paste it anywhere and then include it in your html file. Now Edit the copied **open.js** file on line 66 after:

**if (!file.read) {**

```
    return dfrd.reject(['errOpen', file.name, 'errPerm']);
```

**}**,

and put here:

**return false;**